# C# - Why my TaskScheduler is replaced by the default one after certain await calls?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, taskscheduler

I'm trying to set a custom `TaskScheduler`, but it's not working for nested async methods. The scheduler changes mysteriously to the default. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyApp
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var scheduler = new MyTaskScheduler();
            var context = new MySynchronizationContext(scheduler);
            context.Post(Run, null);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }

        private static void Run(object state)
        {
            RunAsync(); // no await here, intentional.
        }

        private static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            Logger.WriteLine("Before InternalRunAsync"); // <-- Scheduler OK.
            await InternalRunAsync();
            Logger.WriteLine("After InternalRunAsync"); // <-- Scheduler changed. WHY???
        }

        private static async Task InternalRunAsync()
        {
            Logger.WriteLine("Before Delay"); // <-- Scheduler OK.
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
            Logger.WriteLine("After Delay"); // <-- Scheduler OK.
        }
    }

    internal static class Logger
    {
        private static readonly Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        public static void WriteLine(string msg)
        {
            var nativeThreadId = AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId();
            var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current?.ToString() ?? "null";
            var scheduler = TaskScheduler.Current.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"[{sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} native:{nativeThreadId} managed:{threadId} syncCtx:{syncContext} sch:{scheduler}] {msg}");
        }
    }

    internal sealed class MySynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
    {
        private readonly MyTaskScheduler scheduler;

        public MySynchronizationContext(MyTaskScheduler scheduler)
        {
            this.scheduler = scheduler;
        }

        public override SynchronizationContext CreateCopy()
        {
            return new MySynchronizationContext(scheduler);
        }

        public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
        {
            var caller = new SetContextWrapper(this, d, state);
            new Task(caller.Run).Start(scheduler);
        }

        public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
        {
            var caller = new SetContextWrapper(this, d, state);
            new Task(caller.Run).RunSynchronously(scheduler);
        }

        private sealed class SetContextWrapper
        {
            private readonly MySynchronizationContext _context;
            private readonly SendOrPostCallback _callback;
            private readonly object _state;

            public SetContextWrapper(MySynchronizationContext context, SendOrPostCallback callback, object state)
            {
                _context = context;
                _callback = callback;
                _state = state;
            }

            public void Run()
            {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(_context);
                _callback(_state);
            }
        }
    }

    internal sealed class MyTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
    {
        protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(RunTask, task);
        }

        private void RunTask(object state)
        {
            var task = (Task) state;
            TryExecuteTask(task);
        }

        protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
        {
            return TryExecuteTask(task);
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
        {
            return new List<Task>();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[0.0003366 native:13400 managed:3 syncCtx:MyApp.MySynchronizationContext sch:MyApp.MyTaskScheduler] Before InternalRunAsync
[0.0016017 native:13400 managed:3 syncCtx:MyApp.MySynchronizationContext sch:MyApp.MyTaskScheduler] Before Delay
[1.5056582 native:13400 managed:3 syncCtx:MyApp.MySynchronizationContext sch:MyApp.MyTaskScheduler] After Delay
[1.5059042 native:13400 managed:3 syncCtx:MyApp.MySynchronizationContext sch:System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler] After InternalRunAsync
```

Note the last line. It shows that after the method `InternalRunAsync` returns, the scheduler was reset to `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`. Why?

Comment: `TaskScheduler.Current` is defined as [`TaskScheduler` of currently executing `Task`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskScheduler.cs,371). Task that represent `async` method is never considered current. `SynchronizationContext` continuation can bypass `SynchronizationContext`'s `Post`/`Send` and inline itself in current thread, when [it is already in target `SynchronizationContext`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs,417).

Comment: I know. But the continuation is a child of a task that is using the right scheduler. The continuation that prints "After Delay" use the right scheduler. Then there is no thread switch, and the second continuation uses a different scheduler. Why the scheduler changes?

Comment: *Then there is no thread switch* That is not true. That thread is not belong to you while your program await `Task.Delay`. It is just coincidence that continuation happens to run in the same thread. You just need to add more logging and you will see that more than one thread involved.

Comment: I mean there is no thread switch between `After Delay` (which uses the right scheduler) and `After InternalRunAsync` (which uses the wrong scheduler).

Comment: `After Delay` is posted thru `SynchronizationContext`, which executed continuation in task. `After InternalRunAsync` is inlined, thus its code does not belong to any `Task`.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. If somebody calls `Task.Start` or `Task.RunSynchronously`, a different scheduler might be used depending on unrelated stuff such as calls to `await sometask` and nesting level.